# Is it possible to craft armor-piercing ammo while on the reloading bench?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Is it possible to craft armor-piercing ammo yourself on the reloading bench, or can you only find/buy it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on the ammo type you want to create. For instance, you can't produce any of the specialty 9mm ammo yourself - it all has to be bought from vendors.

Specialty Ammo can be produced in the following varieties:

- **.308, JSP Hand Load** -  Increased damage.
- **.357 Magnum, JFP Hand Load** - Increased damage, armor penetration, and reduced spread.
- **.45-70 Government, SWC Hand Load** -  Increased damage, *huge* armor penetration.
- **.50 MG Match Hand Load** -  Increased damage, reduced spread.
- **10mm, JHP Hand Load** - Increased damage, at the cost of increased target Armor.
- **12 Ga. Coin Shot** - A cheaper variant of Buckshot.
- **12 Ga. Slug**, **20 Ga. Slug** - Reduced Spread.
- **12 Ga. Magnum**, **20 Ga. Magnum** -  Increased damage.

Additionally, all Energy Weapon cells (Energy Cell, Microfusion Cell, and Electron Charge Packs), can be produced in both Over Charge and Max Charge varieties for increased damage.

Note: many of these ammunition types, in addition to doing increased damage, will cause the durability of your gun to decay substantially faster. Use only as needed, and with caution!