# Are there any bonuses to making your own ammo?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Is there a benefit to crafting your own ammo in Fallout: New Vegas?  At first I wanted to do it, then I quickly got bored with it, and now its pretty much the LAST thing I want to do in the game.

Anyone do anything otherwise? Should I really bother breaking down ammo, trying to find materials to make an ammo recipe?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some of the crafted ammo is *substantially better* than anything you can buy. Examples include Max Charge ammo for energy weapons, which deal **75%** more damage, and the various Hand-Load ammunition, which often negates armor or has extremely large damage bonuses. You can see [all of the crafted ammo that's better than what you can buy here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9498/crafting-armor-piercing-ammo-in-fallout-new-vegas)

Additionally, if you're playing on hardcore mode, ammo components (lead, powder, primers, cases, spent energy cells, etc.) have no weight, but actual Ammunition does. Especially with Energy Weapons an Veronica as a companion, you can substantially cut down on your carry weight by crafting ammo on an as-needed basis.

Comment: Also works with ED-E.

Comment: Lead has weight, but I think it still lighter than assembled ammo.